# How to add copyright symbol in React component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im want to write copyright symbol in React component, but this doesnt work.

```js
function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer>
      <p>&copy</p>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

`<p>&copy</p>`  works in HTML online editor.

Comment: Have you tried <p>
&#169;
</p>

Comment: You're missing a `;`

Comment: you missed the `;` &copy;

Comment: `&#169; Foo - 2021`

Comment: You can use the unicode if you'd prefer: `<p>{'\u00a9'}</p>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wrote what you had in HTML and ran it through a [validator](https://validator.nu/) it would report:

> Error: Named character reference was not terminated by a semicolon. (Or `&` should have been escaped as `&amp;`.)

Most HTML parsers perform a **lot** of error recovery. JSX is not so forgiving. The semi-colon on the end of a [character reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references) is mandatory:

```
<p>&copy;</p>
```

Alternatively, just use a copyright sign directly:

```
<p>©</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&copy;` for the copyright symbol in React component.

```
function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer>
      <p>&copy;</p>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use  this tag it works event i used the same
in HTML: &copy
in JSX : © or direct ©